# Regarding opencv 3.0.0 and updating sift feature module in anaconda IDE

Tags: python, opencv

Currently I am using windows 8.1 64 bit machine and anaconda as IDE. I am getting the error as shown below. please help me how to update module. Import cv2 is working fine but not with sift features.

File "C:\Users\conquistador\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "C:/Users/conquistador/Documents/opencv/test8.py", line 15, in sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because SIFT (which is considered patent-encumbered or non-free) has been moved from the opencv package to the opencv "contrib" repo. You need a version of cv2 that has been compiled specifically with the contrib included.

Alternatively in cv2, use ORB instead of SIFT.